# Insert JSON data to Crossrider DataBase Showing Error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crossrider

I am Creating Chrome Extension(Add-On's) using Crossrider.What I am doing here is Calling wcf service which retrieve JOSN Data(2 columns with 10 rows). The data is commming but when I am inserting this JSON data in crossrider DB is showing Errror (Error Code 405). I was exactly done what was in crossrider Async.db Demo. The below is my Code

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
appAPI.db.async.setFromRemote('Url which retrieves JSON Data',    // The url for the request
                        'URLs',            // The database key name
                        appAPI.time.daysFromNow(7),  // optional: expiration
                        function(response) {         // optional: success callback
                          alert(Successfully saved.');
                        },
                        function(status) {           //optional: failure callback
                          alert('Failed  error code: ' + status);
                        });
});
```

Comment: In order to help you, please provide a real code snippet with relevant URLs and callback functions. This will enable me to help you resolve your issue. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Assuming the error code is an HTTP error, [405 is Method Not Allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) aka using a GET when the server only supports a POST.

Comment: @abraham is correct about the error message, but you're claiming that the data is received. Which callback is triggered, the success OR failure? Also, if you want me to look into the issue you must provide a valid URL for 'Url which retrieves JSON Data' so that I can test the scenario.

Comment: @Shlomo Thanks for your reply, I unable to provide Url while ask question, My url is http://localhost:3706/Service1.svc/json/GetAffiliatedUrlsCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I done another process to Insert JSON data to crossriderDB.
Step:1) Using appAPI.request.post I get the JSON data and Parse the JSON data

```
     appAPI.request.post({

    url: 'http://localhost:3706/Service1.svc/json/GetAffiliatedUrlsCollection',
    onSuccess: function(response){
   var site = appAPI.JSON.parse(response);//Parse the JSON Data 
    alert(response);
    AddUrlToDB(site);//Calling function to Insertdata to db and passing Parsed JSON data
    },        
    onFailure: function(httpCode) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve content. (HTTP Code:' + httpCode + ')');
    },
    additionalRequestHeaders: {
        myHeader: 'value'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Step:2) Here is the Code to insert JSON data to DB, I wrote this code in the function and this function is calling from the above code

```
    function AddUrlToDB(site){
appAPI.db.async.set("StoredUrls", site, appAPI.time.hoursFromNow(12),
    function() {
        alert("Successfully saved key-value pair to the local database");
    });
}
```

Step:3) Check the data from database

```
    appAPI.db.async.get("StoredUrls",function(value){
if(value===null || value===undefined){
alert('no data');
}
else{alert(value);}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. You preempted my next step and I'm pleased to see you managed to come to the same conclusion on your own ;-)